# is a "tests" folder somehow treated differently in pycharm/python?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am having trouble importing a function stored in a folder called `tests`. E.g. from `main.py`:

```
# this works
from dqm.myfun import thisfun

# this doesnt 
from tests.myfun2 import thisfun2
```

This is how my project looks like:

```
mydir
├── tests
│   └── myfun2.py
├── dqm
│   └── myfun.py
└── main.py
```

If I swtich the functions I get the same problem, so it must be that pycharm does not let me read from a subfolder `tests` for some reason? What am I missing here?

Comment: do you have `__init__` file in both ?

Comment: You can have problems if folders have the same name of other python libraries, pay attention to use different names to avoid errors. Also try python relative imports

Comment: @BeliaevMaksim no I don't (for now)

Comment: try to add it and see, you should create a so called "package"